# suggestions to attack an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you deal with such an integral? Any tips will be appreciated!

$$\int_0^{\infty} \left[\prod_{k=1}^K \sum_{j=0}^k a_j  x^j\right] f(x) \, dx$$

$a_j$ is a constant not depending on $x$, $f(x)$ is some function of $x$. My question is how to deal with the integral of the product...

Comment: What is $\mathrm{cst}_j$?

Comment: Constant strain triangle element?

Comment: sorry, $\textrm{cst}_j$ is a real number not depending on $x$.

Comment: You can take the product, the sum and the constant outside the integral.

Comment: Are you sure you've given this correctly? Every term is going to diverge for nonzero $a_j$.

Comment: SORRY again! I forgot to write $f(x)$. Let me edit. I am confused!

Comment: We need some conditions on $f$, don't we?

Comment: @David Giraudo: Yes, probably. Actually, I am not looking for an exact result. Instead I would like to understand the strategy to attack such an integral

Comment: @ChrisTaylor *You can take the product .../... outside the integral*... I very much doubt one can.

Comment: @did: me too :(

Comment: It seems to me the strategy for analyzing the integral depends on $f$.

Comment: @did oops, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously first multiplier is a polynomial of some degree $N=\sum_{k=0}^K k=K(K+1)/2$. Call this polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{N} b_i x^{i}$. Then you get
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \left[\prod_{k=1}^K \sum_{j=0}^k a_j  x^j\right] f(x)dx=
\int_0^{\infty} \left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N} b_i x^{i}\right] f(x) dx=
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N} b_i\int_0^{\infty}  x^{i} f(x) dx
$$
Hence to attack this integral it is enough to

- Compute integrals $\int_0^{\infty}  x^{i} f(x) dx$ for all $i=0,\ldots,N$
- Compute coefficients $b_i$, this is very messy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I have edited the question because I made a mistake. I am confused!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Indeed, computed $b_i$ looks very messy!

Comment: @user7064 even if you get explicit formula for $b_i$ it will be also very messy. So horrible mess is unavoidable in this approach.